# Enable branding option in Reporting Service 2019

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I have installed Reporting Services 2019 version 15.0.8270.42049.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS2wy.png)

And i want customize the interfaz. I've search several tutorials and i see that should be load a archive in the branding option. But in my portal not have this option. How i can enable it?.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KuzM.png)

Thank you!!!

I've search the configuration of the site, in the configuration archives but i can't find options.

Comment: Branding is only available in SQL Server Enterprise Edition, which version do you have? You can check using the following command `SELECT @@Version`

Comment: Ok, thank you, my version is standard...Thank you so much!!!!